# automatically execute the program with args

Tags: java, cmd, args

I'm building a tool which should convert from format A to format B via Windows command prompt. I programmed something like an interactive mode. The cmd waits for input commands and process them.
Now I wanted to pass some args if I call the progam. The args will be passed but the program won't execute the commands by itself.

I'm passing args like this:

`java -jar test.jar -interactive //activates the interactive mode, which does not make any problems`

and like this (passing the source file, the target place to save the converted file, the target format and finally the config file used during conversion):

`java -jar test.jar C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.json C:\Users\User\Desktop .xes C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.properties`

code so far:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    if (args[0].equals("-interactive")) {
        testing test = new testing();
        test.startCMD();
    } else if (args[0] != null && args[1] != null && args[2] != null && args[3] != null) {
        final testing test = new testing();
        test.startCMD();
        //the following construct doesn't work unfortunatelly
        worker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                    test.setSourceFile(args[0]);
                    test.setTargetPath(args[1]);
                    test.setTargetFormat(args[2]);
                    test.setConfigFilePath(args[3]);
                    System.out.println("Invoking the conversion routine now ...");
                    ConverterControl control = new ConverterControl();
                    control.link(sourceFilePath, targetPath, configFilePath, targetFormat, fileConfig);
            }

        };
        worker.schedule(task, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}

public void startCMD() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] command
            = {
                "cmd",};
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
    new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Windows command line prompt." + System.lineSeparator());
    System.out.println("Please type \"help\" to receive a list of commands available in this environment.");
    //String s = in.readLine();
    String input;
    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
        //process the inputs
}
```

The different `setter` you see in the main method just set the passed information to a variable which is declared at the top of the class. And afterwards these variables should be passed to `ConverterControl` which has the whole conversion routine in its `link()` method.
The program stops if I do pass 4 arguments (see second call of the program at the top) after executing the `startCMD()` command.

Does anyone know how to invoke these methods and start `ConverterControl` automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely stuck in the while loop at the end of `startCmd()`, and your program never continues any further.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling startCMD() if you have received command line arguments?

As an aside, It looks like you may also be misusing static variables a bit.

To tidy this up a lot, your 'testing' class should be implementing Runnable, and you should pass the reference to your 'test' object into your worker.

```
if (args[0].equals("-interactive")) {
    testing test = new testing();
    test.startCMD();
} else if (args[0] != null && args[1] != null && args[2] != null && args[3] != null) {
                final testing test = new testing();
        test.startCMD();//Why is this call here?

        test.setSourceFile(args[0]);
        test.setTargetPath(args[1]);
        test.setTargetFormat(args[2]);
        test.setConfigFilePath(args[3]);

        worker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        worker.schedule(test, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

The rest of the run() method will simply be moved out into a run() method in your 'testing' class.

```
@Override
        public void run() {
                ConverterControl control = new ConverterControl();
                control.link(sourceFilePath, targetPath, configFilePath, targetFormat, fileConfig);
        }
```